# Regex for the first 8-digit number in a block of text excluding numbers with > 8 digits

Tags: regex

I need to check a block of text from an email for a number that's exactly 8 digits long, and only return the first match.

Here are my test cases:

> Test123456789 -- should fail because 9 digits
>
> Test23456789Test -- pass
>
> Test23456789 Test -- pass
>
> 13456780Test -- pass
>
> Test0123456 -- fail because 7 digits
>
> Extra text in the email: I’ve attached the information you requested. If you have any questions, please let us know. -- extra text in the email shouldn't matter.

I've tried:
`.*(\d{8}).*` -- matches multiples
`.*?(\d{8}).*`  -- only one match but it also matches on a 9 digit number
`.*(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d).*` -- I found in another answer but it returns all of the text in the email and I only want the 8 digit number.

Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: What happens if the text contains many numbers, some of which are 7, 8 or 9 digits long, in any order?

Comment: I'm trying to match the first 8 digit number in the entire email email. Also, if the text contains 7 or 9 digit numbers I want to ignore them and only return the first 8 digit number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?!.*\d{9})\d{8}
```

It starts by using a `negative look ahead` for 9 digits. Then it matches `8 digits`.

This will fail if there's 7 or 9 digits.

Answer (score 0):

A small tweak to the last version you posted:

Try: `.*(?<!\d)(\d{8})(?!\d).*`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/P8YGOL/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could find the first occurrence using:

`^[\s\S]+?(?<!\d)(\d{8})(?!\d)`

That will match:

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `[\s\S]+?` Match any character non greedy
- `(?<!\d)` negative lookbehind to check what is on the left is not a digit
- `(\d{8})` Capture 8 digits in a group
- `(?!\d)` Negative lookahead to check what is on the right is not a digit

Or enable make the dot match the newline in your tool or language or prefix the regex with `(?s)` and replace `[\s\S]+?` with `.+?`

Your value is in the first capturing group.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/plG3rG/1)

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, you can use negative look ahead and negative look behind, and remember to not include a `g` flag or else you'll match every occurrence of the pattern:

`(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d)`

[Demo (global match)](https://regex101.com/r/Dpcw4Y/1)